# Redirect IP address to Domain Name in Amazon Web Services EC2

Tags: redirects, amazon-aws

I have just set up a WordPress website using this [tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-a-wordpress-website/). The site can be accessed via domain name as well as IP address. This doesn't look good and I would like the IP to direct to the domain name instead of rendering the page.

Please tell me the possible ways to achieve this. I don't have shell access, but if that's the only way, then I might know that as well.

Comment: How did you create an EC2 server without shell access.? The first step after bringing one up is generally to connect via SSH shell.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller what can i tell. This tutorial specifically told to leave the key/pair unchecked while setting up.

Comment: I see, it uses an AMI that has WordPress installed and running.  I'd recommend installing the key pair and getting shell access so you have a chance of fixing things that break or making config changes.    Have you tried setting the site URL in the WordPress settings yet?

Comment: Well then I guess I need to start over again and do the same thing with key/pair checked